# ADB not recognizing Moto G

Tags: adb, 4.4-kitkat, windows, motorola-moto-g

I've recently acquired a Motorola Moto G, and I plan to use it for development.
I downloaded ADT, updated the SDK tools and the KitKat platform, but Eclipse still doesn't recognise my device. I'm using 4.4.2 and the respective SDKs. USB debugging is enabled, and tried connecting with and without media sharing enabled.

Any idea of how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the problem by installing [Motorola Device Manager](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481/action/auth) and re-plugging the phone.

I felt so silly after finding that link.

Answer (score 0):

For Development you need adb and adb driver.

You can download adb driver from http://adbdriver.com/

You can download adb from [15 seconds ADB Installer v1.4.3 | xda-developers.com](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2588979)